# I am using uiautomator tool in android. In some cast, uiautomator cant draw. I want to customize uiautomator to enable drawing

Tags: android-uiautomator

I want to modify uiautomator source code of android.

Can anybody tell me how i can download the full project and import it to Eclipse.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from here-

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/uiautomator/

Using Github, this would be the command-

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/uiautomator

Comment: Thanks srikanth. I already downloaded it. But when i import as Java project or Android project, It showed error. I want to import it, change source code and re-build jar file.